# RDF and uuid. why no urn schema?

Tags: uri, rdf, uuid, urn

```
<rdf:Description about='uuid:8949dbc6-31ad-11d9-9c7d-d112c21f7031'>
```

Why this `about` does not contain `urn:uuid:8949dbc6-31ad-11d9-9c7d-d112c21f7031` instead? Isn't the uuid a urn, and therefore required to have a urn: scheme in front of it ?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see your RDF closely. The problem in the RDF validator is not the uri itslef but you used 'about' instead of 'rdf:about'. changing this attribute makes your document OK.

Comment: If the problem "why does my rdf not validate with this particular software" - it should have been the question.

Comment: no, the problem is why the URI specified as an argument of the rdf about does not contain urn:uuid:, as from standard, and why this seems to be the norm (if you search for rdf uuid on google you will see that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the chain of specifications, the IANA [URN namespace registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/urn-namespaces/) does indeed register 'uuid' as a namespace after 'urn:'.  So yes, the URL above is wrong and it should start 'urn:uuid' as you were expecting.

Comment: the fact is that if you search with google, you find a lot of URI like that one.

Comment: It is still wrong, however many times you find evidence of that on the web with some search engine.

Answer (score 1):

This URI is wrong. Using the following RDF document in the [W3C RDF Validator](http://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/) returns an error

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <rdf:Description about='uuid:8949dbc6-31ad-11d9-9c7d-d112c21f7031'>
    <dc:title>Hello</dc:title> 
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

**Error: {W102} unqualified use of rdf:about is deprecated.[Line = 4, Column = 70]**

Comment: In fact, the problem comes from "rdf:about" see my comment in the header, please.

Comment: ah, right. unqualified of the about, not of the argument of the about.